# How do I see a jQuery-UI object's settings in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome-devtools

I have a field that I am configuring in Javascript.  I'd like to view the settings in Chrome developer tools.  But when I say,

```
$("#event_date").datepicker
```

in the console, I just get the function.  How do I look at the options?

Comment: `$("#event_date").data()` or an extension like [jQuery Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi) or [jQuery Audit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-audit/dhhnpbajdcgdmbbcoakfhmfgmemlncjg).

Comment: Sure enough!   And `$("#event_date").data().datepicker.o.format = "dd/mm/yyyy"` allows me to set fields.  Please change your comment into an answer so I can give you the points.

Comment: IDK, I see many [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google-chrome-devtools+jquery+data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wOxxOm said, easiest way to view the options is to use the [jQuery data function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) as follows:

```
$("#event_date").data()
```